# Building classes

Tags: c#, android

So I have old code for a minesweeper game and i'm trying to add it to a mobile version with C#.  This might sound stupid but I've never used this before but for some reason it wont let me make instantiate my Game class. Any help?

Mainly  `Game mineSweeper = new Game;` is underlined.

[image]

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App3
{
[Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

      GridLayout gl = (GridLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.MineField);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource


        Button[] cells = new Button[100];

        Game mineSweeper = new Game;

        var i = 0;
        foreach (Button b in cells)
        {
            cells[i] = new Button(this);
            cells[i].Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
            gl.AddView(cells[i]);
            i++;
        }


    }
    private void addButtions()
    {

    }

    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        // identify which button was clicked and perform necessary actions

        button.Text = ("!");
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your Game class?

Comment: `Game minesweeper = new Game();`

Answer (score 0):

Your Game class is in solution items, you should add a seperate Class Library project to the solution and add your Game and Cell classes to it.
Then right click on App3 References and choose Add reference, check your newly created project and click Ok.
Make sure the classes are marked public.
You seem to have forgotten parenthesises in your instantiation, is it a typo? Anyway, instantiate your class like this:

```
Game mineSweeper = new Game();
```

Comment: Yes it was. I just added the classes to the App3 section and it seemed to like it. Or is there a proper way where they should be put?

Comment: No you don't have much layers in your app just leave them in the App3 project.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the reference of the assembly that contains the Type Game in your startup project or not. Also how have you defined Game. Have you given public access to it by the public access keyword or not?